# Java Process Builder builds the process successfully but when flushing information returns Stream closed (java.ioException)

Tags: java, linux, process

Environment Information

OS: Linux( java program running in a docker container)

Java version: 1.8

Node version: 10.22.1

I am trying to create a process from an executable js file with the java ProcessBuilder class like below:

```
String command = "/node/app/bin/app.js"
final ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command);
Process process = pb.start();
OutputStream out = process.getOutputStream();
 out.write("\n[:--:]".getBytes());
out.flush();// this line throws the error java.io.IOException: Stream closed
```

After running the `pb.start()` the process is created successfully, below is the debug information:
[image]

The problem is when the `out.flush()` command which throws an exception when executed. Below is the execution error:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Stream closed

at java.lang.ProcessBuilder$NullOutputStream.write(ProcessBuilder.java:433) ~[?:1.8.0_292]

at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:116) ~[?:1.8.0_292]

at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82) ~[?:1.8.0_292]

at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140) ~[?:1.8.0_292]
```

The `/node/app/bin/app.js` content is like below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
var path = require('path');

var apJsFile = path.resolve(__dirname, '../app.js'); //app.js is working correctly

require(appJsFile);
```

Comment: Try redirecting the process input explicitly: `pb.redirectInput(Redirect.PIPE)`.

Comment: I added `pb.redirectInput(Redirect.PIPE)` after `final ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command)`, but still continues to throw the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sub-process is likely to be reporting an error and exits while you are writing to the stdin of the sub-process `getOutputStream()` - hence stream closed. As you are not consuming stdout and stderr streams correctly you haven't had a chance to read any error message.

An easy way to check is to redirect stdout and stderr to a file to inspect afterwards:

```
pb.redirectOutput(new File("std.out"));          
pb.redirectError(new File("std.err"));
Process process = pb.start();
...
int rc = p.waitFor();
```

Those files may help you spot the actual problem. The most rebust way to deal with `ProcessBuilder` is to use consumer tasks in background threads to deal with sub-process stdin, stdout and stderr and wait for these consumers to finish after `waitFor()`. That will prevent sub-process stall / freeze if I/O is pending on any one of the streams: `getOutputStream()`, `getInputStream()` and `getErrorStream()`.

Comment: That help me diagnose the cause of the problem. Thank you for  your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The command `/node/app/bin/app.js` when executed on my environment directly in linux container was not working.
Since `pb.start()` was not throwing any exception I thought this was not a problem of the command itself because it will have caused the start method to throw an exception.

After fixing the error `/node/app/bin/app.js`(it was a formatting issue and shebangs was not working properly) then the error caused by `out.flush()` disappeared.